# avoiding impossible cases in macro

Tags: c++, string, macros

consider the following macro:

```
#define checkExists(map, it, value) {\
    it = map.find(value);\
    if(it == map.end()){\
        if(!strcmp(typeid(value).name(), "Ss")){ /* value is an std::string */\
            manageError(ERR_CANT_FIND_RESSOURCES, "in %s __ failed to find %s in map %s", __FUNCTION__, value.c_str(), #map);\
        \
        }else if(!(strcmp(typeid(value).name(), "Pc") * strcmp(typeid(value).name(), "PKc"))){ /* value is either char* or const char* */\
            manageError(ERR_CANT_FIND_RESSOURCES, "in %s __ failed to find %s in map %s", __FUNCTION__, value #map); /* problem here because for gcc value could be an std::string */ \
        \
        } else \
            manageError(ERR_CANT_FIND_RESSOURCES, "in %s __ failed to find 0x%04X in map %s", __FUNCTION__, value #map); /* problem here because for gcc value could be an std::string */\
    }\
}
```

`manageError` is a also a macro that calls a function `logWarning` which only accepts only fundamental types (eg `int`, `char*` ...). The prototypes are:

```
#define manageError(error_code, error_str, ...) {\
    {\
        logWarning(error_str, ##__VA_ARGS__);\
        return error_code;\
    }\
}

int logWarning(const char* printf_format, ...);
```

So if my `value` is an `std::string`, I am giving `manageError` a `const char *`.

It's seems like `checkExists` isn't evaluated compile time... so gcc being very clever, it doesn't allow me the last two `manageError` calls, because it sees `value` as an `std::string` or it's impossible because `std::string` is only possible in the first case.

For example, this doesn't work:

```
std::string foo;
checkExists(myMap, myMapIterator, foo);
```

gcc output:

```
error: cannot pass objects of non-trivially-copyable type 'const string {aka const struct std::basic_string<char>}' through '...'
```

Do you know how I can solve this issue ?

**Edit**

the idea of that mecanism is to be able to leave the current function if an error occured. For example:

```
int func(){
    std::string foo;
    checkExists(myMap, myMapIterator, foo); //leaves the function if foo is not found inside myMap
    return 0;
}
```

so I have to use macro to be able to leave the function (not possible for me to use templates).

Comment: @Jarod42 I am using C++ (don't mind C-like instructions).

Comment: @Jarod42 updated it, but thought it would give the same solution since C methods are valid in C++.

Comment: How about template?

Comment: @Jarod42 please consider my edit

Comment: @tony_merguez OK, so making the function into a template is out; but you can still use template metaprogramming and `if constexpr` (namely with `std::is_same_v`).

Comment: Note that the names returned by `typeid::name()` are not standardized. This code is likely to have different behavior with different compilers.

Comment: @Pete Becker, it's not an issue for me, it will always be built with my old fashion gcc.

Comment: Also, `strcmp` returns 0 when the two strings are the same, and non-zero if they're different. So `if (!strcmp(...))` will be true whenever the strings match. I suspect that's the reverse of what you want.

Comment: @PeteBecker I am using C++0x, do you have any example for me please ?

Comment: @PeteBecker I confirm you that what is written corresponds to what I want to do

Comment: Okay, I see what you're doing there. You want to give a different message, depending on the type of `value`; that sounds like an overloaded function.

Comment: @PeteBecker it's the idea, but as far as I know, it's not possible with macros... don't know how I can find a convenient solution.

Comment: Why use a macro? Consider a function template as @Jarod42 suggests. If you want, add a macro to that to get the enclosing function name. But by convention, macros should be `ALL_CAPS_SNAKE_CASE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by converting `value` to `std::string` no matter the input type.

```
#define checkExists(map, it, value) {\
    it = map.find(value);\
    if(it == map.end()){\
        std::stringstream tmpSs;\
        if(!(strcmp(typeid(value).name(), "Pc") * strcmp(typeid(value).name(), "PKc") * strcmp(typeid(value).name(), "Ss"))){\
            tmpSs << value;\
        }else{\
            tmpSs << "0x" << std::uppercase << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(4) << std::hex << value; /* converting value to hex format */\
        }\
        \
        manageError(ERRCAN_T_FIND_RESSOURCES, "in %s __ failed to find %s in map %s", __FUNCTION__, tmpSs.str().c_str(), #map);\
    }\
}
```

Comment: As we said, overload/template might simplify the code: `template <typename T>std::string to_string(const T& t) { if constexpr (std::is_same_v<const char*, T> || std::is_same_v<std::string, T>)  return p; else { std::stringstream ss; ss << "0x" << std::uppercase << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(4) << std::hex << t; return ss.str(); }}` and then your MACRO is simply `#define checkExists(map, it, value) { it = map.find(value);     if(it == map.end()){ manageError(ERRCAN_T_FIND_RESSOURCES, "in %s __ failed to find %s in map %s", __FUNCTION__, to_string(value).c_str(), #map);`

Comment: @Jarod42 thank you for the `std::is_same` trick, I will use it instead of `typeid`. But in my humble opinion you're just splitting my 'macro' to a 'macro + template function'. Btw in `to_string`, I don't think that `p `corresponds to anything (`return p`). But thanks anyway.

Comment: Typo: `return t;`. And indeed idea is to split MACRO. limit MACRO to the part which is only doable in MACRO.